# Blank window problem when connecting Mist to `geth`

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I used:
 - OS: Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.1
 - geth:  1.5.7-stable-da2a22c3

I followed these installation instructions: https://github.com/ethereum/mist

When I try to run `Mist`, I get a blank window (see below). Please note that `Mist` was able to successfully connect into `geth.ipc`.

```
$ cd mist
$ electron .
```

`Mist`'s blank window:

[image]

**Error Message:**

```
main - Running in production mode: false
Secp256k1 bindings are not compiled. Pure JS implementation will be used.
main - Starting in Mist mode
Db - Creating db: undefined
Db - Loading db: undefined
Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
updateChecker - Check for update...
Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
Windows - Create primary window: splash, owner: notset
ipcCommunicator - Backend language set to:  en-US
ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
ClientBinaryManager - Resolving path to Eth client binary ...
ClientBinaryManager - Eth client binary path: /Users/avatar/mist/nodes/eth/mac-x64/eth
lientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json
updateChecker - App is up-to-date.
ClientBinaryManager - No "skippedNodeVersion.json" found.
ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...
ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
ClientBinaryManager - Sanity check failed for Geth Error: Unable to find "1.5.9" in Geth output
  at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (/Users/avatar/mist/node_modules/ethereum-client-binaries/src/index.js:635:17)
Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc/geth.ipc"}
Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
NodeSync - Ethereum node connected, re-start sync
NodeSync - Starting sync loop
Sockets/3 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc/geth.ipc"}
main - Connected via IPC to node.
Sockets/3 - Connected!
NodeSync - No more sync necessary
main - Loading Interface at http://localhost:3000
NodeSync - Sync loop ended
Sockets/2 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc/geth.ipc"}
Sockets/2 - Connected!
Windows - All primary windows closed/invisible, so quitting app...
main - Defer quitting until sockets and node are shut down
Sockets - Destroy all sockets
Sockets/2 - Disconnecting...
Sockets/3 - Disconnecting...
Sockets/node-ipc - Disconnecting...
main - About to quit...
Windows - All primary windows closed/invisible, so quitting app...
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Maybe something to do with "Sanity check failed for Geth Error: Unable to find "1.5.9" in Geth output"? How did you install the current version of Geth?

Comment: Solution could be find here: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1686. I did not done `cd mist/interface && meteor`.

Comment: Please answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1686](http://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1686). I had forgotten to do `cd mist/interface && meteor`.